# How to create a file using scala methods?

Tags: scala

In Java it does so:

```
File dir1 = new File("C://SomeDir");
File file1 = new File("C://SomeDir", "Hello.txt");
File file2 = new File(dir1, "Hello2.txt");
```

I need to find a function or method that can create a file using scala.

Comment: Java libraries are available to the Scala compiler. Just `import java.io.File` and use the same code.

Comment: Or prefer java.nio.file.Path for constructing the path.